# HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request bitbucket

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I am trying to use jenkins and bitbucket.org for CI/CD. I installed jenkins to ubuntu (aws). And I created a job in jenkins. Also I added jeenkins ssh key to bitbucket.org.

So I can reach with ssh to bitbucket from jenkins. Bu when I try to push bitbucket.org I saw an error in webhooks logs.

It says:

```
HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944119/jenkins-error-403-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in-the-request

Comment: Thanks but this  solved my problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57731818/jenkins-2-192-http-error-403-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in-the-request